# Abstract Concept Assignment

Tags: java, implementation, abstract

So my questions are geared directly to my homework. Before you ask, yes I've looked at other questions and I have looked at the java docs to try and help me but I only understand so much..

You have become a restaurant mogul.  You own several fast food chains.  However, you now need to set a standard that all of your fast food chain must follow in order to have your software be uniform across the board.  There will be some rules that will be the same for all restaurants.

Create an Abstract Class named Restaurant

Create a function/method that will print the name of the restaurant when called.

Create an abstract function/method named total price

Create an abstract function/method named menu items

Create an abstract function/method name location

Create a Class called McDonalds that extends Restaurant

Implement all abstract methods

Add logic so that the total price method/function will give the total price of the meal including a 6% tax

Add a method that returns a Boolean named hasPlayPlace.  Which returns true when this location has a playplace

Create a Constructor that will set the name of the Mcdonalds, location, and hasPlayPlace

```
public class McDonalds extends Restaurant {
    private String name;
    private String location;
    private boolean hasPlayPlace;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public McDonalds (String name, String location, boolean hasPlayPlace) {
        setName(name);
        setLocation(location);
        setHasPlayPlace(hasPlayPlace);
    }

    McDonalds location1 = new McDonalds("McDonalds", "Kirkman", false);
    McDonalds location2 = new McDonalds("McDonalds 2", "International Dr.", true);

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    public void setLocation(String location){
        this.location = location;
    }
    public boolean isHasPlayPlace() {
        return hasPlayPlace;
    }
    public void setHasPlayPlace(boolean hasPlayPlace) {
        this.hasPlayPlace = hasPlayPlace;
    }


    public void totalPrice() {
        double totalPrice = 0;
        double tax = 0.06;
        totalPrice += (totalPrice * tax);       
    }

    public void menuItems() {
            //some syntax is wrong in this method
        double mcChicken = 1;
        double fries = 1.25;
        System.out.println("1. Mc Chicken $1");
        System.out.println("2. Fries $1.25");
        int choice = input.nextInt();
        switch (choice){
        case 1: mcChicken *= tax;
        case 2: fries *= tax;
        }

    }

    public void location() {
        //Don't know what's supposed to go in here.
        //But I've implemented the method as I was supposed to.
    }

}
```

Does it all make sense is basically what i'm asking.
What should go in the location method?
What's the use of getters and setters within this class and did I do it right?

Comment: McDonalds have names now!? (other than McDonalds, of course)

Comment: Don't use char for a name, use String. String literals are written in " ", so use `"McDonald"` instead of `McDonald` (analog to Kirman)

Comment: This is a very confused and confusing question. How are you calling your methods? What are the **questions** you're asking. (Beyond "can someone fix everything that looks wrong?") What does the menu you mention have to do with anything? What does "Can I have multiple objects for one constructor?" even mean?

Comment: I'm beyong confused myself. I would post the entire questions along with my code but I don't wanna get in trouble or get banned. Not looking for anyone to do my homework.

Answer (score 2):

Name and location should be `String` not `char`.

I like the style of calling setters from within the constructor, because its a form of code reuse, especially if there are special checks being made on those values, such as not being null - calling he setter means you only check this in one place.

Your code won't compile, but you're close:

```
McDonalds location1 = new McDonalds("Some name", "Kirkman", true);
```

Your calculation is a little off too:

```
double tax = 0.06;
totalPrice *= (tax + 1);
```

However, this is dangerous because if called twice, it will add the tax twice. It would be better to have a method return the tax included price which calculates it every time. Having a getter with side effects is a design error. Ie have thus:

```
public double getTaxIncPrice() {
    double tax = 0.06;
    return totalPrice * (1 + tax);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Your constructor is structured fine, but you should use `String`s instead of `char`s for the name and location. A `char` will only hold one character.

2) You can create multiple instances of a class:

```
McDonalds location1 = new McDonalds("McDonald", "Kirkman", true);
McDonalds location2 = new McDonalds("McDonald2", "Kirkman", false);
```

3) You should add the tax to the price as a percentage, not a sum: `price * 1.06`. Be careful not to change the price w/o tax when you print the total price.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the problem that Bohemian pointed out (name and location should be String, not char):

Your constructor call will need quotes on the String parameters:

```
McDonalds location1 = new McDonalds("McDonald", "Kirkman", true);
```

and your tax calculation is incorrect - you will need to multiply the total amount by the tax percentage, and you will have to wait until you actually have a total to do the calculation.

Comment: Yeah I accidently put "+" when it shouldve been "*"

Comment: That would still be incorrect. If, say, your total amount is $100 and the tax is 6%, then you want the result to $106 - so you would need totalPrice += (totalPrice * tax)

Answer (score 0):

Just editted my code and provided the question. Your guys inputs helped so far.

```
public String TacoBellSauce(String fire, String hot, String mild) {
    System.out.println("What sauce would you like to have?");
    System.out.println("1. Fire");
    System.out.println("2. Hot");
    System.out.println("3. Mild");
    int choice = input.nextInt();
    switch(choice) {
    case 1:
        return fire;
    case 2:
        return hot;
    case 3:
        return mild;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here is also my method for the TacoBell class. How would I return it in the Test class? It says to make a method within TacoBell that returns a string of what hot sauce I would like. But then it says within the test class to call hotsauce and return hot. I haven't created that class yet cause I'm focused on correcting everything with McDonalds and TacoBell.